# Can someone help me solve two equations so I can find the values of two capacitors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a self-taught novice electrical engineer and a, wear all the hats, kind of entrepreneur, with algebra level math skills. I am designing a device that is a minimum viable product which is heading towards a Kickstarter campaign.

The device is a soil moisture sensing and analysis device that uses capacitance sensing technology to help manage soil moisture in your garden. One probe set at the bottom of the device and a second probe set just under the soil line, allow the device to measure soil moisture across the full vertical profile of the soil. Analysis of the data determines if the soil is over-saturated, optimally-saturated, wilting, or dry.

Green, yellow and red, instantly recognized symbols for good, bad and in-between serve as the interface of the device. These colors are used to indicate four discrete levels of soil moisture, and a low battery warning. The device is powered by six 1.2 V, 2300 mAh Low Self Discharge NiMH batteries for a maximum voltage of 8.4 V, which will power the device for the entire growing season.

As a novice I have a limited understanding of EE and therefore my device, much less some of the math that goes with it. One of the components in my design is a wireless power receiver. Connected to this IC is a wireless receiving coil. A resonant circuit is created by the coil and two capacitors. It is the equations to calculate the values for the capacitors that brings me to you. Here are the two equations:

$$C_1 = \left[(f_S \times 2\pi)^2 \times L'_S\right]^{-1}$$
$$C_2 = \left[(f_D \times 2\pi)^2 \times L_S - \frac{1}{C_1}\right]^{-1}$$

The variables are as follows:

$f = Resonant\ Frequency = 148 kHz$
$L = Inductance = 11.5 µH$
$S = unknown$
$D = unknown$

The datasheet has this to say.

> Resonant capacitors C1 and C2 are set according to WPC specification.
> Although this is a dual mode solution,the PMA does not specify an
> exact resonance frequency for the resonant capacitors and in fact does
> not specify that resonant capacitors are indeed needed.

Not very helpful for a novice. One thing that I have difficulty with in EE Math is converting values so that variables have matching magnitudes. For example, 148 kHz x 11.5 µH, vs 148,000 Hz x 0.0000115 H, how do I know what units to think in?

I have no idea what S, D and the apostrophe represent. Could you help me solve these two equations?

Comment: What do the subscripts signify? You haven’t begun to make sense of these equations.

Comment: Perhaps electronics.SE is a better fit for this question. I suggest that you contact the Moderators (click on `Flag` below your question) and request that the question be _migrated_ to electronics.SE. Please don't post a duplicate on electronics .SE, or delete this question here on math.SE and post it on electronics.SE; request _migration_ from the Moderators